# JQuery doesn't load specif image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have an application in Ruby on Rails and I want to load some images in JQuery with ajax. There are 6 images I want to load, all of them loads but the 6th one.

This is my view:

```
<div class="container imageDisplayer">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-offset-md-3 col-md-6">
      <%= f.association :hotspot, include_blank: false,:collection => Hotspot.where('user_id = ?',@user_id), :label => "Hotspot", :label_method => :code, input_html: { class: 'styled-select blue semi-square' }  %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="/assets/logo.png" id="ad1">
      <%= f.input :image1, :label => "1)" %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="/assets/logo.png" id="ad2">
      <%= f.input :image2, :label => "2)" %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="/assets/logo.png" id="ad3">
      <%= f.input :image3, :label => "3)" %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="/assets/logo.png" id="ad4">
      <%= f.input :image4, :label => "4)" %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="/assets/logo.png" id="ad5">
      <%= f.input :image5, :label => "5)" %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img  src="/assets/logo.png" id="ad6">
      <%= f.input :image6, :label => "6)" %>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

my jquery code loads the URLs perfectly, even the 6th one (I even check the image url on anothe tab and it displays the image

this is my JS that loads the URLs

```
function loadImages(hotspot_id){
  console.log(hotspot_id);

  request = {};
  request["hotspot_id"] = hotspot_id

  request = JSON.stringify(request);
  console.log(request);
  $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url:"/get_images",
             data: {
               hotspot: request
             }
           }).done(function(data) {
             console.log(data);

             if (data["result"] == "OK") {

               if(data["1"] != "404"){
                 $("#ad1").attr("src",data["1"]);
               }

               if(data["2"] != "404"){
                 $("#ad2").attr("src",data["2"]);
               }

               if(data["3"] != "404"){
                 $("#ad3").attr("src",data["3"]);
               }

               if(data["4"] != "404"){
                 $("#ad4").attr("src",data["4"]);
               }

               if(data["6"] != "404"){
                 $("#ad6").attr("src",data["6"]);
               }

               if(data["5"] != "404"){
                 $("#ad5").attr("src",data["5"]);
               }


             }
           });
```

the variable data["6"] contains the image URL, but when I try to display it the image comes with width and height 0x0. But all the others images display perfectly! Why is the image 6 not loading?

Just discovered that when I enter on the page, this problem happens, but if I reaload it, it works! (damn)

If I force the a tag image to display the 6th image, it shows perfectly, which means that whats screwing everything is the JS correct?

Comment: `console.log(data["6"])`

Comment: since the same process works for the other images , not likely that it is a javascript problem. Try removing whitespace `$("#ad6").attr("src",data["6"].trim());`

Comment: console printed: https://smartspot.s3.amazonaws.com/original/image_64?1486127356 (which is the image)

Comment: Just discovered that when I enter on the page, this problem happens, but if I reaload it, it works! (damn)